# Como cambiar el color de fondo del form usando design system object

Tags: genexus

Tengo un objeto webpanel con abstract layout. Estoy intentando asignar un color de fondo al form asignandolo en la clase correspondiente con la propiedad background-color.

```
.Form
{
gx-form-popup-class: Popup;
gx-form-nav-style-class: ResponsiveSlide;
enter-effect-composite: Fade 20px 0.5s 0.1 ;
enter-effect: gx_fade;
gx-enter-effect-length: 20px;
gx-enter-effect-duration: 0.5s;
gx-enter-effect-opacity: 0.1;
close-effect-composite: Fade 20px 0.5s 0.1 ;
close-effect: gx_fade;
gx-close-effect-length: 20px;
gx-close-effect-duration: 0.5s;
gx-close-effect-opacity: 0.1;
border-style: none;
border-width: 0px;
height: 100%;
        background-color: $colors.Fondo;
}
```

Pero no esta funcionado, porque al inicio del tag body se genera style fijo con color blanco, y sobreescribe todas las declaraciones de los css

`<body class="Form Form-fx" style="background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); color: rgb(0, 0, 0);" data-hasenter="false" data-skiponenter="false">`

Revisando el _impl.java del programa, veo que se genera al inicio tomando como parametro Form.getIBackground(), pero no pude encontrar como leer que hace la funcion.

`bodyStyle = "" + "background-color:" + WebUtils.getHTMLColor( Form.getIBackground()) + ";color:" + WebUtils.getHTMLColor( Form.getTextcolor()) + ";" ;`

Se agradece cualquier informacion que me pueda encaminar! Desde ya muchas gracias!

Answer (score 0):

Es cierto lo que mencionas, el generador está poniendo un estilo inline que no debería ir (eso lo tenes en el tag body, por lo que el Form que está abajo va a tomar esa configuración).

Le deberias poner asi:

```
.Form
{
   gx-form-popup-class: Popup;
   gx-form-nav-style-class: ResponsiveSlide;
   enter-effect-composite: Fade 20px 0.5s 0.1 ;
   enter-effect: gx_fade;
   gx-enter-effect-length: 20px;
   gx-enter-effect-duration: 0.5s;
   gx-enter-effect-opacity: 0.1;
   close-effect-composite: Fade 20px 0.5s 0.1 ;
   close-effect: gx_fade;
   gx-close-effect-length: 20px;
   gx-close-effect-duration: 0.5s;
   gx-close-effect-opacity: 0.1;
   border-style: none;
   border-width: 0px;
   height: 100%;
   background-color: $colors.Fondo !important;
}
```

Con eso deberia funcionarte ok.